# Как конвертировать, bitmap в ImageSource, пробую не получается

Tags: c#, wpf

Для вывода картинки в WPF я конвертирую иконку от файла в формате bitmap в формат, который будет отображаться в контроле. Вот код.

```
public ImageSource ImageSourceForImageControl(Bitmap yourBitmap)// получаем иконку 
{
    ImageSourceConverter c = new ImageSourceConverter();
    return (ImageSource)c.ConvertFrom(yourBitmap);
}

// получаю иконку от файла, и  пытаюсь сконвертить, не конвертируется. 
temp = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(path).ToBitmap();
ImageSource wpf_icon = ImageSourceForImageControl(temp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   public BitmapImage Convert(Bitmap src)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        ((System.Drawing.Bitmap)src).Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        image.BeginInit();
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        image.StreamSource = ms;
        image.EndInit();
        return image;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

У меня работает так:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;


public BitmapSource GetFileIcon(string path)
{
    using (var sysicon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(path))
        return Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(
                    sysicon.Handle,
                    Int32Rect.Empty,
                    BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, заработало, а подскажите как правильно вывести это дело в разметке

Comment: А в чем проблема? Выставляйте свойство и делайте привязку к нему

Comment: Все выводится, только картинка не выводится, заместо нее пишется System .Windows,Media,Imaging.BitmapImage

Comment: Эээ, а к какому контролу вы привязываете?

Comment: ListView  вот к нему и привязываю

Comment: Ну дык он не умеет картинки показывать, помещайте в шаблон `Image` и выводите картинку в нем

Comment: Дак тоже пытаюсь, студия все время ошибку выдает, вот и не знаю как правильно.вот колонка,  <GridViewColumn Header="Иконка"   DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding A}"/>, как мне из нее сделать колонку с имаджем не знаю.

Comment: Нужно установить `CellTemplate`, примерно как здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4725474/6766879

Comment: Увы не работает пишет ошибка,  <GridViewColumn Header="Иконка"   DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding A}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate >
                    <Image Source="{Binding A}"/>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>

Comment: Потому что вы невнимательны, там ведь не так написано. Проверяйте: `<GridViewColumn Header="Иконка"><GridViewColumn.CellTemplate><DataTemplate><Image Source="{Binding A}"/></DataTemplate></GridViewColumn.CellTemplate></GridViewColumn>`

Comment: Да, все заработало спасибо